# ssis any sugestions to make encoding job easier

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

ssis any sugestions to make encoding job easier.
I have a csv-file in utf-8 and want to insert that into a mssql server with unicode.
As fare as I understand In the toolbox

1. I import a flatfile connection and there I change the code page to 65001(UTF-8)
2. In advanced properties I change the DataType one by one from string[DT_STR] to Unicode string [DT_WSTR].
3. I have to do almost the same procedure for the mssql server as well..

I have about 300 columns to change and in about 100 tables...
That is an massive to do job...

My question is; are there any more effective way to do this????

/jc

Comment: In a Script Task, you could loop through the columns and change the encoding of each.

Comment: You would need a derived column task to create a new column for each.  Due to the extent of the project, you might consider BIML to programatically create the packages

Comment: Perhaps my internationalization ignorance is showing, but in your flat file connection manager, after you change the Code Page, why don't you set the Columns as WSTR instead of STR?